# Creating a table from a GROUP BY uses a lot of temporary disk space - can it be avoided?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, postgresql-10, disk-space, aws-aurora

I've got a table with ~2 billions rows of data, and I would like to make another table with some aggregates. It looks like PostgreSQL uses temporary disk space for these queries. I can create the table...

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_new_table ...
```

But then when I come to insert data:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_new_table SELECT
   col_1,
   col_2,
   col_3,
   col_4,
   col_5,
   col_6,
   col_7,
   col_8,
   col_9,
   sum(col_10),
   sum(col_11)
FROM
   my_table
GROUP BY
   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

PostgreSQL seems to use temporary files for the results, and it's running out of space, e.g. getting errors like:

> could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp31757.25": No space left on device

From looking at the results of an EXPLAIN, I suspect this is from a sort. Is there a way to avoid this? There won't be that many output rows, so somehow I feel as though there should be a way to do it more in place at the output... but that's a very vague intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to re-write the query using some properties of the data to effectively "split up" the GROUP BY so it wouldn't run out of disk.

If there is a column with an index, that has a roughly even distribution of values over the rows, and that has some reasonable amount of unique values so splitting over it makes each split fit onto temporary disk/memory, then you can use this trick that uses a LATERAL JOIN to split up the GROUP BY:

```
INSERT INTO my_new_table SELECT
   a.* 
FROM (
    -- You might need to use a different mechanism to choose all the values 
    -- that the column takes - the one here is only for an integer column.
    -- In other cases, a SELECT DISTINCT might be more appropriate, but in
    -- the cases I tested, that was considerably slower
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(
      (SELECT min(col_1) FROM my_table)::int,
      (SELECT max(col_1) FROM my_table)::int
    )
) c(col_1)
INNER JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT
      t.col_1,
      col_2,
      col_3,
      col_4,
      col_5,
      col_6,
      col_7,
      col_8,
      col_9,
      sum(col_10),
      sum(col_11)
   FROM
      my_table t
   WHERE
      t.col_1 = c.col_1
   GROUP BY
      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
) a ON TRUE;
```

Comment: We don't have `year` field in the question

Comment: @SahapAsci That's true - I think I'm more trying to say that this answer is appropriate if there is some column in the data that means the data can be split so it fits on temporary disk (or even memory). Will see if I can tweak it

Comment: @MichalCharemza: `WHERE t.year = y.year` makes no sense in your query. This might make is work: `... FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(col_1)::int, max(col_1)::int) FROM my_table) y(year) ...`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks! I've now changed it (sticking with "col_1" everywhere to try to make it as generic as possible)

Answer (score 5):

Sorting 2 billion rows will always need a lot of space.

If you know that there will only be a few groups, you could try to get a hash aggregate and avoid the sort. There are two things you can try:

1. Use extended statistics so that the optimizer knows that there will only be a few groups:

   ```
   CREATE STATISTICS groupcount (ndistinct)
      ON col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8, col_9
      FROM my_table;
   ANALYZE my_table;
   ```
2. Force the planner's hand by discouraging sorts:

   ```
   SET enable_sort = off;
   ```

   This will make PostgreSQL prefer plans without a sort in the current session.